# Javascript not loading in Safari sometimes

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, safari

My web page is not loading correctly in Safari Browser when it loads to iframe via JavaScript. Html `head` tag is loading and `body` tag not loading in that case.

But using different network connection it loads perfectly.

Is there any evidence to not loading a website in different networks?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Yes. Is that the case?

Comment: it is the case if you say it is the case

Comment: If you're asking whether that could be a problem, yes it may be.